# In DXA(1.7 version) entity model, how to manage field with both component link and multimedia links?

Tags: dxa

I have a schema field which allows both component link and multimedia links.I have created the below model binding class in DXA.

```
[SemanticProperty("eng:internal_link")]

public string InternalLinkComponent {get;set;}

[SemanticProperty("eng:internal_link")]

public EntityModel BinaryLink {get;set;}
```

Code works fine when I debug in local but after deploying it to Test environments, I am seeing intermittent issue with model binding error. Once I recycle the app pool, the error goes away and it appears again after sometime.

Error : Unable to map field "_article" to property of type "Models._article".

Note: component link field is part of "_article" embedded schema.

Can you please suggest the right way of binding the schema field using DXA entity model.

Comment: Please add a log showing the error

Comment: Unable to map field "_article" to property of type "Models._article".

Comment: Do you actually have a View Model class named `_article`? That’s a remarkable naming convention at least.

Comment: Please provide more info about your View Model types. Which classes do you use? Where do they inherit from? Also check the log file with log level set to DEBUG.

Comment: please provide full log when debug level as DEBUG. and as you have mentioned that its working for some time and app pool recycle fix the problem that is something confusing. if it works then it should work always.